Cannot run peer because could not get peer BCCSP configuration
I am learning how to setup a Hyperledger fabric network. When I'm trying to create a channel useing the following
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/config/
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_CA=$PWD/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA

it prints out the following error
2024-06-22 16:13:21.728 NDT 0001 ERRO [main] InitCmd -> Cannot run peer because could not get peer BCCSP configuration joining peers to channel

This is my part of my docker-compose.yaml
had to cut the files down because stack overflow was complaining
version: '2'

services:
  orderer1.example.com:
    container_name: orderer1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.5
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

# orderer 2 was here

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.5
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    volumes:
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7052:7052

# peer 2 was here

here is the BCCSP part of my crypto-config.yaml
BCCSP:
  Default: SW
  SW:
    Hash: SHA2
    Security: 256
    FileKeyStore:
      KeyStore: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/keystore

any help would be appreciated
